# Trouble with last DROP rule in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

Let's say I want four ports to be opened for any incoming packets so I made this ruleset:

```
#> iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 20 packets, 1190 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1041  103K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:111
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:222
  208 12056 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:333
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:443
```

(forward and output chains are empty)

Let's now say that there is an SSH server running at port 111 and to connect to this machine I do

```
 ssh username@hostna.me -p 111
```

then I login and everything works.

But other ports are also left open because default policy is ACCEPT and I haven't added DROP rule. Now I want to add it and type

```
#> iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

It's a 5th rule.

Now i want to connect again to my opened SSH port. I have a response like `username's password:` but it comes **like 20 seconds later instead of almost instant** without that 5th rule.

So I remove this rule like that

```
#> iptables -D INPUT 5
```

and again I can connect to my SSH without any delay.

**Why is this?**

**What have I blocked that I shouldn't have blocked?**

p.s: There is a web server running at port 443, when I try to connect from a browser, the page loads indefinitely, but server is live.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to open port 53 to whatever your DNS server is.  SSH does a reverse lookup on the incoming IP address -- it *will* connect if it doesn't have reverse resolution, but it will introduce a delay.